# How to give the output of a command as a reference to a variable in bash shell

Tags: linux

I am creating a bash file .sh which will locate the path of a file and store the output of that command to use it later in another command. This is what I've done so far:

```
path_exe=${1:-locate binarycreator}
$path_exe -c config/config.xml -p packages $Name
```

when I'm running it I'm getting this: "locate: invalid option -- 'p'"
Can anyone help me on this please?

Comment: can u do an `echo  $path_exe` after it is set and verify if it has the right value

Comment: yes I've tried it and it has the right value

Comment: Have you tried running the command directly. If it has the right value and is still throwing an error it isnt an issue with the bash variable but an issue with the exe that is being called

Comment: btw the default value is `locate binary_creator` ? With a space in between?. You need to enclose that in quotes

Comment: How are you calling this sh file?

Comment: I've tried it with the static path and the command worked fine but I am avoiding using static paths

Comment: by going to the directory where this file is located and typing ./filename.sh

Comment: I believe what you wanted is `path_exe=${1:-$(locate binarycreator)}`

Comment: If you are using the $1 variable it means ypur shell script accepts an argument, if not provided it uses the default value. If you dont need the argument dont use the $1 variable just use `$(locate bi)narycreator` and store that in a variable

Answer (score -1):

You have to store the first variable as a command. See below example which highlights what you are doing and how it is to be done.

```
bash-5.0$ a=${1:-'which ls'}
bash-5.0$ echo $a
which ls
bash-5.0$ $a
/usr/bin/ls  # Notice only the command is printed but not executed.

--------------------------------------------- 

bash-5.0$ a=$(which ls)
bash-5.0$ echo $a
/usr/bin/ls
bash-5.0$ $a
aliases        bin 
# This executed the command
```